# widget using dynamically generated search queries in twitter widget

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have created an embedded tweets widget using the configuration wizard with a specific query  I thought I should be able to replace some of the parameters  but the widget only ever shows with the original search query. I guess the ID is still connecting with that query.  Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: It's difficult to tell where the problem may be, can you add any further details (e.g. code/errors/expected outcomes etc...) to your question that could help us answer? Thanks!

Comment: Widget displaying the tweets only by the screen name i have given while creating the widget.I need to display the tweets by searching the screen name.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this article: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/18474
So it's not possible (anymore) with the widgets to dynamically set / change the query term.

I tried doing the same thing today and hit upon the same wall.

So according to me, the only solution will be to query twitter via their API and do the rendering at your end.

It's a pitty though that we need to do this... Especially since it was possible before.